# Zend framework 2 add remove button next to form field

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2, templatefield

I have this at the moment:
[image: form field]

It's generated with this code:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'attachments',
    'options' => array(
        'count' => 1,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_remove' => true,
        'target_element' => new AttachmentFieldset($this->entityManager)
    )
));
```

I'd like to add a removal button next to each form field so I'm also able to remove attachments. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi! Your question has a proper answer in the official documentation: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically. Either you haven't seen that or you have further more specific questions, so please add details for us to help you more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a collection, specifying `allow_add` or `allow_remove` does not tell ZF to create the appropriate buttons, only that the collection may contain any number of elements (minimum specified by `count`).

After adding the collection to the form, you also need to add a button that, on click, calls a function to add another element based on the template.

From the manual:

```
<button onclick="return add_category()">Add a new category</button>
```

and

```
<script>
     function add_category() {
         var currentCount = $('form > fieldset > fieldset').length;
         var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
         template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

         $('form > fieldset').append(template);

         return false;
     }
 </script>
```

To add a remove button, alter the above function to add a button to the template, and create a remove function:

```
<script>
     function add_category() {
         var currentCount = $('form > fieldset > fieldset').length;
         var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
         template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount)
                            .replace('</fieldset>', '<button onclick="return remove_category(this)">Remove</button></fieldset>');
         $('form > fieldset').append(template);

         return false;
     }
     function remove_category(el) {
         $(el).parent().remove();
     }
 </script>
```